# Is there any way to know the load time for a java application?

Tags: spring-boot, micronaut, micrometer

I am trying to compare performance of SpringBoot and Micronaut.

I have some applications implemented with both frameworks, and can get some info about JVM with Micrometer, but the information about the time each of these frameworks need to load from scratch and start working is something I am missing.

Is there any way to get it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring boot logs startup time in format:

Started {applicationName} in {time} seconds (JVM running for {jvmTime})

e.g.

```
2019-05-18 20:50:07.099  INFO 6904 --- [           main] c.e.demo.DemoApplication     : Started DemoApplication in 2.156 seconds (JVM running for 3.164)
```

If you want to have access to startup time programmatically in your application you can JVM running time on ApplicationStartedEvent:

```
@Component
public class StartupListener {

  @EventListener
  public void onStartup(ApplicationStartedEvent event) {
    double startupTime = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getUptime() / 1000.0;
    System.out.println("Application started in: " + startupTime);
  }
}
```

---

Just to complete the answer with the Micronaut part:

```java
@Singleton
@Requires(notEnv = Environment.TEST)
@Slf4j
public class InitialEventListener implements ApplicationEventListener<ServiceStartedEvent> {

  @Getter
  private long currentTimeMillis;

  @Async
  @Override
  public void onApplicationEvent(ServiceStartedEvent event) {
    currentTimeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
    log.info("ServiceStartedEvent at " + currentTimeMillis + ":" + event);
  }
}
```